# Issue in copying gradle cache to an offline system

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a laptop in which I am running a Gradle project using the wrapper `gradlew`. The dependencies for this project can only be downloaded from our organization's network. 
My testing team wants to test the project outside our organization network, hence I cannot download the dependencies. So I have copied the entire ".gradle" folder from `C:\\Users\\MyUserName` of my machine to the `C:\\Users\\Admin` of the other system. And I run, `gradlew --offline`. But I get an error stating that the cache has not been found, though the JARS are present in the ".gradle" directory. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: If the testing team is "outside our organization network" it is maybe better to hand them over not the complete build, but just the result bundled with all the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradle cache folder is not supposed to be copyied to different directories as some paths stored in there are referenced by absolute path. You would need to run your build at least from with gradle user home C://Users/Admin to get it working on your offline system later with --offline

I'd use a dedicated folder for that (like `C:/gradle-cache`) and set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to point to that directory or use the `-g` option in gradle to specify the gradle cache folder.

There's a bug in Gradle at the moment that prevents the Wrapper to respect the `-g` option (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1895) . So as you seem to use the wrapper, you probably should go with the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable.

Then on your target system you copy the cache to `C:/gradle-cache` again and also set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` and your offline build should work.

Comment: I am using your method for copying entire gradle user home between my windows PC s. And it works fine - I suspect gradle again downloads the project dependencies - anyway the trick bypasses wrapper distribution downloaded and other bulky network operations.

Comment: Now I am dual my windows laptop with Ubuntu. I copied my entire gradle user home directory from windows drive to Ubuntu drive and set the gradle user home variable to that directory- and surprisingly it works. Again I suspect gradle downloads project dependencies - anyway it bypasses wrapper distribution downloads and other bulky network operations.

Comment: In present, I have two gradle user home diectories - one in Ubuntu drive and one in windows drive. While working on Ubuntu - both are accessible. Can I sym link my gradle user directory on windows drive as gradle cache folder in Ubuntu or use it directly as Ubuntu gradle cache folder? - i am using Android studio in both OS.